# How to set a timeout on PHP5 curl calls? Published CURL options do not seem to work

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, curl-multi

We've written a script that pulls data from an external server.  If the server goes down we don't want our server waiting for the data since we process a lot of data and we don't want it bogged down.  To address this, we're trying to timeout our curl calls if they take more than a couple hundred milliseconds.

I found some documentation saying that CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS and CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS should be available in my version of php and libcurl, but it does not seem to be timing out, even if I set the timeout to 1ms.

```
$url = "http://www.cnn.com;

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0); //Change this to a 1 to return headers
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 1);

            $data = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);
```

Does anyone know what we're doing wrong or another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

saw this in [unresponsive dns server and curl multi timeouts not working](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2008-06/0006.html):

> "...We have had some times where a
>   site that we pull information has had
>   dns server become unresponsive.  When
>   this happens the timeouts set in curl
>   (php bindings) do not work as
>   expected.  It times out after 1min 14
>   sec with "Could not resolve host:
>   www.yahoo.com (Domain name not found)"
>   To make this happen in test env we
>   modify /etc/resolv.conf to have a
>   nameserver that does not exist
>   (nameserver 1.1.1.1).  No mater what
>   they are set at
>
> ```
> (CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS 
> , CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS)
> ```
>
> they don't timeout when we cant get
>   to the DNS server.  I use curl_multi
>   because i we have multiple sources
>   that we pull info from at the same
>   time.  The example below makes one
>   call for example simplicity.  And as a
>   side note curl_errno does not return
>   an error code even though there was an
>   error. Not sure why..."